# Write a single query to search between two dates and when To date is not available then it should search greater then first date

Tags: sql-server, database

Write a single query to search between two dates and when To date is not available then it should search greater then first date.

For example: search between two dates, when both from and to dates are available

```
11-10-2015 to 11-10-2017
```

My query should also return result when To date is not available

For example: I want to write single query without any if and else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works and it is a single statement, as requested.

SELECT * from MyTable WHERE recordingdate BETWEEN **COALESCE(@startdate,CAST('01/01/1753 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME))** AND **COALESCE(@enddate,CAST('12/31/9999 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME))**

If the start date is NULL, COALESCE will return the minimum date value, as defined by SQL Server.  Otherwise, it returns the start date value sent in.

If the end date is NULL, COALESCE will return the maximum date value, as defined by SQL Server.  Otherwise, it returns the end date sent in.

Feel free to turn the COALESCE statements for MIN and MAX possible dates into functions, as SQL Server does not have built-in functions for minimum and maximum possible dates.

Writing your code this way allows you to always execute a BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0):

Try Thie below Logic

```
DECLARE @FromDt DATE='01/01/2017',@ToDate DATE = NULL

SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable
        WHERE FromDate > @FromDate
            AND
            (
                @ToDate IS NULL
                OR
                (
                    @ToDate IS NOT NULL
                    AND
                    ToDate > @ToDate
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt_from date = '20151011', 
        @dt_to date = '20171011' -- null

select *
from dbo.your_table
where date_field >= @dt_from and data <= isnull(@dt_to, '99990101');
```